# apache digester sax parser exception

Tags: apache-commons-digester

I'm trying to use Apache Digester to parse my SOAP response, but am getting SaxParserException. Here is what I have:

**Main.java**

```
Digester digester = org.apache.commons.digester3.binder.DigesterLoader
            .newLoader(new FromAnnotationsRuleModule() {

                @Override
                protected void configureRules() {
                    bindRulesFrom(SubmitResponse.class);
                }

            }).newDigester();
SubmitResponse response = digester.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><SubmitResponse xmlns=\"http://schemas.example.com/digitalrequest/v5.00\"><SubmitResult xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/example.Lib.v500\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><a:ID>0</a:ID><a:TaskResponses><a:TaskResponse><a:Task><a:WorkOrderID>0</a:WorkOrderID></a:Task></a:TaskResponse></a:TaskResponses></SubmitResult></SubmitResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>"
                        .getBytes()));
```

**SubmitResponse.java**

```
@ObjectCreate(pattern = "s:Envelope")
public class SubmitResponse implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<TaskResponse> taskResponses;

    public List<TaskResponse> getTaskResponses() {
        return taskResponses;
    }

    public void setTaskResponses(List<TaskResponse> taskResponses) {
        this.taskResponses = taskResponses;
    }

    @SetNext
    public void addTaskResponses(TaskResponse taskResponse) {
        this.taskResponses.add(taskResponse);
    }
}
```

**TaskResponse.java**

```
@ObjectCreate(pattern = "s:Envelope/s:Body/SubmitResponse/SubmitResult/a:TaskResponses/a:TaskResponse")
public class TaskResponse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @BeanPropertySetter(pattern = "a:Task/a:WorkOrderID")
    private String workorderId;

    public String getWorkorderId() {
        return workorderId;
    }

    public void setTaskResponseList(String workorderId) {
        this.workorderId = workorderId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TaskResponse [workorderId=" + workorderId + "]";
    }

}
```

But this code is giving me SaxParserException. I'm guessing that I'm not giving the correct pattern. Can somebody please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look beyond the `SaxParserException` to the root cause. This is a `NullPointerException` in the `addTaskResponses` method. From there, it is evident that the `taskResponses` is never initialised, so you need to create a list before trying to add things to it:

```
private List<TaskResponse> taskResponses = new ArrayList<>();
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Barney. That solved the `SaxParserException`. I was being so stupid here. Can you tell me what should be the pattern so that I get the value of `a:WorkOrderID`?

Comment: @Praz: never used annotations, but I'd try just giving it the full path rather than a relative one - i.e. `s:Envelope/s:Body/.../a:Task/a:WorkOrderID`. Note also that in your code above you do not have a `setWorkorderId` method (looks like a cut and paste error - it is called `setTaskResponseList`) so the `BeanPropertySetter` will not find a match - this may also be your problem.

Comment: Good catch. The setter method and relative path was the issue. Thanks a lot.